# Simple SQL Query 1

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using PL/SQL if that matters.

```
Table = Stuff

ID:   FRUIT:
100   Apple
100   Grape
200   Apple
200   Orange
550   Apple
700   Orange
800   Orange
900   Grape
...   ...
```

I want to list all of the Apples and their IDs that do NOT share the same ID as Orange.  How do I go about doing this?

The output should be:

```
100   Apple
550   Apple
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you show us your expected output and possibly a query you have tried.

Comment: Edited, thanks!  I don't have a SQL query because I don't know if it's a join or inner select :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a subquery so you effectively pick all of the ID's for Oranges out in this subquery then pick all of the fruit which are Apples and ID's aren't in the subquery.  Something like this;

```
SELECT *
FROM stuff
WHERE fruit = 'Apple'
    AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM stuff WHERE fruit = 'Orange')
```

Comment: This one was the simplest and easiest to understand for a beginner like myself, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are subtracting one set of records from another and a subquery will do the job.
Edited for your new data set

```
select * 
from stuff 
where fruit = 'Apple'
and id not in (
select ID from stuff where fruit != 'Apple'
);
```

Or you could use a MINUS query as well.

Comment: I think you need an extra filter for the apples

Comment: @vc74 It's hard to say with the information we have to go on.

Comment: If there are bananas, tangelos and papayas, the not in clause would need to include them as well.  Given the information, I woudl say that kevinsky's answer is as complete and correct as is possible.

Comment: But this query would include non Apples which ID is not one of the oranges' although the OP stated:  list all of the Apples.

Comment: Sorry about my OP.  There are many other fruits and many other IDs.  I edited the OP to include this in case it wasn't clear, as this doesn't filter out the other fruits.

Answer (score 1):

You can select only once from the table using `CASE EXPRESSION` and a `GROUP BY WITH HAVING` clause like this :

```
SELECT t.id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.FRUIT = 'Apple' THEN t.FRUIT end) as fruit
FROM stuff t
GROUP BY t.id
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN t.FRUIT = 'Orange' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Comment: I'm not this advanced yet but I'm going to keep it handy for when I learn some of those new statements (Max, Case, etc).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are no need to build up full list of Orange's IDs, just use `not exist`:

```
select * 
from 
  stuff apple_list
where 
  fruit = 'Apple'
  and 
  not exists (
    select null 
    from stuff orange_instance 
    where orange_instance.id = apple_list.id
  )
```

or do same thing with outer join:

```
select  
  id, fruit 
from (
  select 
    apple_list.id,  
    apple_list.fruit,
    nvl2(orange_instance.id, 'orange_here', 'no_orange') orange_flag
  from 
    stuff apple_list,
    stuff orange_instance
  where 
    apple_list.fruit = 'Apple'
    and
    orange_instance.id (+) = apple_list.id
    and
    orange_instance.fruit (+) = 'Orange'
)
where 
  orange_flag = 'no_orange'
```

Second variant needs `distinct` in select if there are possibility of having two Oranges with same id.

Comment: These are great examples!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do it using the MINUS set operator:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.FRUIT
  FROM STUFF a
  WHERE a.FRUIT = 'Apple'
MINUS
SELECT b.ID, 'Apple' AS FRUIT
  FROM STUFF b
  WHERE b.FRUIT = 'Orange'
```

Best of luck.